# copy files from source to destination with uuid renaming

Tags: bash

I have some files in a recursive folder structure, which I would like to copy to destination and give them a uuid name instead of the original name (because the names collide).

Nonrmally I would do something like this:

```
SOURCE_DIR="/some/*/dir/struct/*/img_files" &&\
DEST_DIR="/dest/folder/0" &&\
rm -rf $DEST_DIR &&\
mkdir -p $DEST_DIR &&\
find $SOURCE_DIR \( -name "*.jpg" \) -exec cp {} $DEST_DIR \;
```

but because the names collide, I am unable to do this. Thus, I would like to assign a uuid name to each file which is being copied. To this end, I have tried this:

```
SOURCE_DIR="/some/*/dir/struct/*/img_files" &&\
DEST_DIR="/dest/folder/0" &&\
rm -rf $DEST_DIR &&\
mkdir -p $DEST_DIR &&\
find $SOURCE_DIR \( -name "*.jpg" \) -exec cp {} $DEST_DIR/"$(uuidgen).jpg" \;
```

but I get only copied file :( rather than a bunch of files in the folders.

Comment: What do you mean that you only get a copied file rather than a bunch of files in the folders? That isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're only getting one file is because when the shell parses your `find` command, it expands `$(uuidgen)` to the result of running `uuidgen` and then passes that *as a static string* to `find`. You also have some other, minor issues:

- avoid using CAPS for variable names since that is by convention used for global environment variables and variable name collisions can be hard to debug.
- Your `find` is needlessly complicated.
- [Always quote your variables!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222)
- No need for `\`  after `&&`, the `&&` is enough, but it is also not needed for the variable declarations.
  Here's a working version of your script with some improvements:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir="/some/*/dir/struct/*/img_files" 
dest_dir="/dest/folder/0" 
source_dir="."
dest_dir="bar"
rm -rf "$dest_dir" &&
  mkdir -p "$dest_dir" &&
  find "$source_dir" -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'name='$dest_dir'/$(uuidgen).jpg; cp "$1" "$name"' sh {} \;
```

The trick is to call an `sh` script from within `find`. This takes care of the rest. We need to pass it `sh` (or any other random string, it just needs a 1st and 2nd argument) and `{}` because the first argument becomes `$0` in this context, so we need a second to get `$1`.

Comment: thank you! you saved my day today! I will try and adhere to the principles you have stated